# How to set wiredTigerCacheSize in mongodb when deployed in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I would like to set the mongodb wiredTigerCacheSize in my kubernetes deployment (linux).
In docker I could simply define:

> docker run -d --name my-mongo mongo --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 0.25

but not in kubernetes...

I have the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-mongo-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-mongo-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-mongo-db
        image: mongo
        env:
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
```

so far I have tried (did not work):

```
lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "mongod --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 0.25"]
```

Comment: Did you check the docs for "storage"?

Comment: @Minsky I did, but no luck...

Comment: Please include the link

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/

Comment: u need to look in the correct context. This is, where the config file's structure you input is defined

Comment: `storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB:<size>` https://dev4devs.com/2018/08/03/mongodb-wiredtiger-and-memory-usage-in-containers/ and links therein. Each `.` means a sub level as you wrote in the current config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading (thanks to Minsky who pointed me in the right direction) I have found the following solution to work:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-mongo-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-mongo-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-mongo-db
        image: mongo
        command: ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
        args: ["mongod", "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB", "0.25"]
        env:
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
```